# For Loop error as method

Tags: java

I am trying to write a `code` that changes a value by either -1 or +1 depending on a random chance. It is basically a person moving through blocks. He starts from 6 and if he ends up in 1 he wins but if he ends up in 11 he loses. The final output would look something like this:

```
   Here we go again... time for a walk!
   Walked 37 blocks, and
   Landed at Home

   Here we go again... time for a walk!
   Walked 19 blocks, and
   Landed in JAIL

   Here we go again... time for a walk!
   Walked 13 blocks, and
   Landed in JAIL

   Here we go again... time for a walk!
   Walked 25 blocks, and
   Landed in JAIL
```

I have written the following code:

```
public class Drunk {
    public int street;
    public double move;
    public int i;
    public boolean jail;

   public static void drunkWalk() {
       do {
           street = 6;
           move = Math.random();
           i++;
           if (move > 0.5) {
               street++;
           } else {
               street--;
           }
       } while (street != 1 && street != 11);
       if ( street == 1) {
           jail = false;
       } else {
           jail = true;
       }
    for (; ; ) { --- } //This is the problem. It treats it as a method. 
                     //How can I fix this?
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the loop inside the method.

Comment: The `for loop` is outside the method

Comment: @Rakesh When I try that it gives me `non static variable can not be reference from static context` all over the code

Comment: @Keppil  When I try that it gives me `non static variable can not be reference from static context` all over the code

Comment: Yes, that is another problem. `drunkWalk` is a static method, but all the variables declared on class level are not static.

Comment: @Keppil How can I fix that? I just remove the static?

Comment: You can make class members such as `street` and `move` static if that does not affect instantiation.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve with the `Drunk` class. Like @DizzyCode says, if you are planning on creating multiple `Drunk` people, then remove the `static` qualifier from the method. If you are not planning on creating any `Drunk` objects, then make the class variables `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about somethink like:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Drunk drunk = new Drunk();
    while (true) 
     { 
         DrunkResult result = drunk.drunkWalkToJail();
         System.out.println("Walked " + result.getSteps() + " blocks, and Landed at " + (result.isInJail() ? "Jail":"Home"));
     } 
}
public DrunkResult drunkWalkToJail()
{
    int street;
    int stepCount = 0;

    do
    {
        street = 6;
        double move = Math.random();
        stepCount++;
        if (move > 0.5)
        {
            street++;
        }
        else
        {
            street--;
        }
    }
    while (street != 1 && street != 11);

    return new DrunkResult(street == 11, stepCount);
}
```

and

```
public class DrunkResult
{
    boolean jail = false;

    int stepCount = 0;

    public DrunkResult(boolean jail, int stepCount)
    {
        this.jail = jail;
        this.stepCount = stepCount;
    }

    public boolean isInJail()
    {
        return jail;
    }

    public int getSteps()
    {
        return stepCount;

    }

}
```

You can do walks in parallel (a group of drunk people) and process the results independent.